# How to draw lemniscate with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

How to draw e.g. the given set (known as Brauer Cassini Ovals)

```
     { z : |z-a|·|z-b| <= c }
```

in the complex plane

The question is just about how to draw this (filled or unfilled) curve, not how to the coordinate system or something else.

Is there an easy way to do this with TikZ or do I have to use pstricks / gnuplot / or somethin similar?

I would prefer using TikZ only, because I already have a complex plot done in TikZ, to which I want to add some of those lemniscates.

Comment: Posting a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image will increase the likelihood that people will be able/willing to help you and the speed at which they will be able to help you. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Also, an image showing your desired result would come in handy as well. :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]

This `MWE` using `Asymptote` uses `cassinioval.asy` module
to build a Cassini oval as either one or two closed curves,
constructed as a `polargraph`. It is constructed at the origin
and then rotated and shifted to the location of foci `A` and `B`,
see examples 1,2.

```
% cassini.tex :
%
\begin{filecontents*}{cassinioval.asy}
import graph;

// The polar representation used according to
// A.A. Savelov, "Planar curves" , pp.147--148, Moscow (1960) (In Russian),
// see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval
//
struct CassiniOval{
// { z : |z-A|·|z-B| <= C }
  pair A, B; real C;
  int npoints;

  real a,c;
  transform transf;
  real alpha;

  guide[] curve;

  real rho(real phi){
    return c*sqrt(abs(cos(2phi)+sqrt(abs(cos(2phi)^2+(a/c)^4-1))));
  };

  real rho2(real phi){
    return c*sqrt(abs(cos(2phi)-sqrt(abs(cos(2phi)^2+(a/c)^4-1))));
  };

  guide[] normLscate(){
    guide[] g;
    guide q;
    real xMax=sqrt(a^2+c^2);
    real xMin=-xMax;
    if(a>=c){// one contour;
      g.push(transf*(polargraph(rho,0,2pi,npoints)--cycle));
    }else{// two contours;
      q=polargraph(rho,-alpha,alpha,npoints)
        --reverse(polargraph(rho2,-alpha,alpha,npoints))
        --cycle;
      g=(transf*q)^^(transf*reflect(N,S)*q);

    }
    return g;
  }

  void operator init(pair A, pair B, real C, int npoints=300){
    assert(C>0);
    this.A=A; this.B=B;  this.C=C;
    assert(npoints>1);
    this.npoints=npoints;
    this.c=arclength(A--B)/2;
    this.a=sqrt(C);
    transf=shift(A)*rotate(degrees(atan2(B.y-A.y,B.x-A.x)))*shift(c,0);

    if(a<c){alpha=asin((a/c)^2)/2;}
    curve=normLscate();    
  }
}
\end{filecontents*}
%
%
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \centering
      \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
\begin{asy}
import cassinioval;
size(5cm);
pair A=(-2,0);
pair B=(2,0);
real C=5;

CassiniOval co=CassiniOval(A,B,C);

pen cpen=deepblue;
pen fpen=lightgreen;

fill(co.curve,fpen);
draw(co.curve,cpen);

dot(A,UnFill);
dot(B,UnFill);
label("$A$",A,W);
label("$B$",B,E);

pair Ap=(0,-2);
pair Bp=(0,2);

fpen=lightred+opacity(0.5);
filldraw(CassiniOval(Ap,Bp,C).curve,fpen,cpen);

dot(Ap,UnFill);
dot(Bp,UnFill);
label("$A^\prime$",Ap,W);
label("$B^\prime$",Bp,E);
\end{asy}
%
\caption{Example 1}
\label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
\begin{asy}
import cassinioval;
size(5cm);
pen cpen=deepblue;
pen fpen=lightgreen+opacity(0.2);

pair A=(-3,-1);
pair B=(2,3);
real C;
CassiniOval co;

for(int i=6;i<16;++i){
  C=i;
  co=CassiniOval(A,B,C);
  filldraw(co.curve,fpen,cpen);
}

dot(A,UnFill);
dot(B,UnFill);
label("$A$",A,W);
label("$B$",B,E);

\end{asy}
%
\caption{Example 2}
\label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
%
\end{document}
%
% Process:
%
% pdflatex cassini.tex    
% asy cassini-*.asy    
% pdflatex cassini.tex
```

Comment: That looks very nice, thank you! But I am not able to include that an existing *tikzpicture*-environment, am I? So I think I have to extend your example and rewrite my existing *tikzpicture*, right?

Comment: @stg: Yes, feel free to convert it to `TikZ`.

Comment: I get the following output if I ran asy cassini_*.asy

Comment: An update in Asymptote made it run GhostScript with the `-dSAFER` option enabled by default, which [makes code with `opacity` (such as this one) fail](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473911/134574). The solution in this case is to pass the `-nosafe` option to `asy` to make this code work.

Comment: @ S. Venkataraman: Also, check out 
[Ghostscript error when using opacity](https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/f2ecb64b19/).

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun: a Ti*k*Z version. The strategy is very much as in [g.kov's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/27243/g-kov). The syntax is

```
\draw[Cassini curve=with centers A and B and constant pi];
```

where the centers denote the two points and the constant what is called `c` in the question.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={%
rhoone(\a,\c,\t)=sqrt(\a^2*cos(2*\t)-sqrt(-2*\a^4 + 64*\c^2 + 2*\a^4*cos(4*\t))/2)/2;
rhotwo(\a,\c,\t)=sqrt(\a^2*cos(2*\t)+sqrt(-2*\a^4 + 64*\c^2+2*\a^4*cos(4*\t))/2)/2;},
Cassini curve/.style args={with centers #1 and #2 and constant #3}{%
insert path={
let \p1=($(#2)-(#1)$),\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)/1cm},\n2={atan2(\x1,\y1)}
in %\pgfextra{\typeout{#1,#2,#3,\n1,\n2}}
[shift={($(#2)!0.5!(#1)$)}]
plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=101] 
(\t-\n2+90:{rhotwo(\n1,#3,\t)})
}}]
\path (0,0) coordinate (A) (3,1) coordinate (B) (-2,-2) coordinate (C);
\foreach \X in {A,B,C} {\fill (\X) circle (1pt) node[below]{\X};}
\draw[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.3,Cassini curve=with centers A and B and constant pi];
\draw[fill=red,fill opacity=0.3,Cassini curve=with centers A and C and constant pi];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]