# Cassini oval curve in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am interested in drawing Cassini oval curve that has two foci `A(-1,0) , B (1,0)` and the other parameter is `3`. I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152627/how-to-draw-lemniscate-with-tikz) but it won't suit my needs since asympote is not compiled by my LaTeX version and I have not worked with it before neither have I gotten to know it.

So, I am wondering if we can do it with tikz instead. In any comment in the linked question it says that someone would translate it to tikz but it does seem to be a link. Maybe I am wrong though and there is somewhere a solution using tikz **exclusively**.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since you're familiar with TikZ, what have you tried so far?

Comment: http://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf might be useful.

Comment: @cfr Actually I only know basic staff of tikz. Draw something like this , well, I would have no idea where to begin. So, I have tried nothing.

Comment: If you know Tikz, you can translate my answer (22.5 Plotting a Function etc...). tkz-fct is based on Tikz and uses gnuplot so you need to install gnuplot but for complex function I think it's "indispensable".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to determine a good domain and some coefficients.
Update for the color

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
   \tkzInit [xmin=-1,xmax=1,
             ymin=-1,ymax=1,
             xstep=.2,ystep=.2]
  \foreach \i in {4,3.8,...,1.2}    {%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{8*\i}
  \tkzFctPolar[domain=-pi:pi,fill=green!\n!white]{%
  sqrt(cos(2*t)+sqrt(\i-sin(2*t)*sin(2*t)))}  
  \tkzFctPolar[domain=-pi:pi,fill=green!\n!white]{%
  sqrt(cos(2*t)+sqrt(\i+sin(2*t)*sin(2*t)))}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alain. One question. How do we fill that , e.g with a color say light green?

Comment: @Tolaso No problem I updated my answer. you need to use the loop with decreasing numbers

Comment: engine ? for me lualatex. viewer ? when you compile you get a result ? you have gnuplot installed ?

Comment: Hang on a minute... I have to run it with LuaLaTeX? I have gnuplot installed. Engine is PDFLaTeX... When I compile I do not get a result , just a blank page.

P.S: I accepted your answer as it is close to what I want to do.

Comment: OK, solved.. !! I was doing something wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Polar coordinates seems a good way to draw the curve as plot with the angle as parameter. The radius can be calculated with the second equation of the [Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cassinische_Kurve&oldid=145265760).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x=2cm,
  y=2cm,
]
  \def\samples{180}
  \def\c{1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\cc{\c*\c}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\cccc{\cc*\cc}
  \def\a{1.01}
  \foreach\a in {1.001, 1.01, 1.05, 1.1, 1.3, 1.6, 2, 2.5, 3} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\aa{\a*\a}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\aaaa{\aa*\aa}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\aaaaMcccc{\aaaa - \cccc}
    \draw
      plot[
        variable=\t,
        domain=0:360-1/\samples,
        samples=\samples,
        smooth cycle,
      ]
      (\t:{\cc*sqrt(\cc*cos(2*\t) + sqrt(\cccc*cos(2*\t)*cos(2*\t) + \aaaaMcccc))})
    ;
  }
  \path plot[mark=x] coordinates { (-\c, 0) (\c, 0) };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The angle is `\t`, the foci can be configured with `\c`. The example shows the curves for different values of `\a`.

### Lemniscate

In this case `\a` equals `\c`, this simplifies the formula. Since the angles are now non-continuous, the curve is drawn in two parts, first the right, then the left. Also filling is shown.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x=2cm,
  y=2cm,
]
  \def\samples{100}
  \def\c{1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\cc{\c*\c}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\cccc{\cc*\cc}
  \def\a{1.01}
  \draw[fill=green!50!white]
    (0, 0) --
    plot[
      variable=\t,
      domain=-45+1/\samples:45-1/\samples,
      samples=\samples,
      smooth,
    ]
    (\t:{\cc*sqrt(\cc*cos(2*\t) + \cc*cos(2*\t))})
    -- cycle
  ;
  \draw[fill=green!50!white]
    (0, 0) --
    plot[
      variable=\t,
      domain=180-45+1/\samples:180+45-1/\samples,
      samples=\samples,
      smooth,
    ]
    (\t:{\cc*sqrt(\cc*cos(2*\t) + \cc*cos(2*\t))})
    -- cycle
  ;
  \path plot[mark=x] coordinates { (-\c, 0) (\c, 0) };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks @Heiko . But this does not compile. I get an error of "Package PGF Math Error: I cannot calculate the square-root of the negative nu"

Comment: Or you can use tikz with gnuplot

Comment: @Tolaso `\a` must be greater than `\c`. The other cases with smaller `\a` are not implemented, since the question says that the other parameter is 3, three times greater than 1.

Answer (score 4):

Run with `xelatex`. It uses the implicit defined function and the variables `\rA` and `\rC`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=2}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
\psaxes[labels=none,Dx=0.5,Dy=0.5,ticksize=-3pt 3pt]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
\def\rC{1} 
\pgfforeach \rA in {0,0.2,...,1.6}{%
\psplotImp[linewidth=1pt,algebraic,linecolor=blue!60]%
  (-3,-3)(3,3){(x^2+y^2)^2-2*\rC^2*(x^2-y^2)-\rA^4+\rC^4}}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
\psaxes[labels=none,Dx=0.5,Dy=0.5,ticksize=-3pt 3pt]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
\def\rC{2} 
\pgfforeach \rA in {0,0.2,...,2.4}{%
    \psplotImp[linewidth=1pt,algebraic,linecolor=red!60]%
    (-3,-3)(3,3){(x^2+y^2)^2-2*\rC^2*(x^2-y^2)-\rA^4+\rC^4}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice Herbert.. Nice of pstricks... !