# Error in asymptote using upacity to draw a lemniscate

Tags: errors, asymptote

I am trying to draw a lemniscate using the code from this answer:
[How to draw lemniscate with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152627/how-to-draw-lemniscate-with-tikz?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However, if when I run asymptote I get the following error messages:

```
Error: /undefined in .setopacityalpha
Operand stack:
   0.5
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2045   1   3   %oparray_pop   2044   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   2025   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:967/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:82/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 31005
GPL Ghostscript 9.26: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1                                                                                                                                                                                       
/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/asymptote/plain_shipout.asy: 87.10: runtime: shipout failed                                                                                                                                                     
Error: /undefined in .setopacityalpha                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Operand stack:                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   0.2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Execution stack:                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2045   1   3   %oparray_pop   2044   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   2025   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--              
Dictionary stack:                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
   --dict:967/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:82/200(L)--                                                                                                                                                                          
Current allocation mode is local                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Current file position is 38506                                                                                                                                                                                                               
GPL Ghostscript 9.26: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1                                                                                                                                                                                       
/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/asymptote/plain_shipout.asy: 87.10: runtime: shipout failed
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wow.

After a *lot* of digging I found [this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1632030) (which isn't actually a bug) which suggests that GhostScript (which is called by Asymptote) runs into problems when opacity is used along the the `-dSAFER` option. This option assures that no PostScript code which could be harmful to the system is executed. Enabling this option makes the opacity fail. If you change the line `fpen=lightred+opacity(0.5);` to `fpen=lightred;//+opacity(0.5);` and `pen fpen=lightgreen+opacity(0.2);` to `pen fpen=lightgreen;//+opacity(0.2);` (commenting out the opacity) the picture is generated:

> [image]

but it's not what you'd expect. And if you enable the opacity the problem persists because Asymptote calls GhostScript with `-dSAFER` by default since 2008 (from the change log):

```
commit 407a627a5d18b773739a9535b486b8a177dd7c49
Author: John Bowman <bowman@ualberta.ca>
Date:   Mon Jun 23 11:00:40 2008 -0600

    By default run gs with -dSAFER.
```

After more digging through code and documentation looking for `opacity` without success, I searched for `safe` and voilà:

> [image]

there is a `-nosafe` option which you can (**when you trust the code your are executing**) pass to `asy` so that the opacity will work.

So you can use the same code from the answer you linked ([How to draw lemniscate with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152730/134574)) and compile the document with:

```
pdflatex cassini.tex
asy -nosafe cassini-*asy
pdflatex cassini.tex
```

and it will work :)

Answer (score 6):

A better workaround for this ghostscript bug has already been implemented in the git source (and will be in the upcoming 2.48 Asymptote release):

https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/issues/77

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this error while using pstricks in general, I found a solution in  [different question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/550094/66458). So give the original author an upvote, if this works for you:

```
% GhostScript 9.53
\usepackage[pspdf={-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY}]{pstricks-pdf}
% GhostScript < 9.53
\usepackage[pspdf={-dNOSAFER}]{pstricks-pdf}
```