# How can I rotate an already existing 2D/3D graph or shape along some axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, rotating

First off, I'm total novice at this.

I have a graph like :

[image: this]

And I want to rotate this plotted graph along the x-axis to get something like:

[image: this]

So Is there a way/online tool /piece of code to do this kind of operation(rotation along any axis) in TeXStudio using Tikz-PGF, LaTex or do I have to write complete code for the output myself? Please suggest.

PS: I have to work with both 2D/3D graphs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run with `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>`

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[pspdf={-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY}]{pstricks-pdf}% GhostScript 9.53
\usepackage[pspdf={-dNOSAFER}]{pstricks-pdf}%  < 9.53
\usepackage{pst-func}
\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=2} 
\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-4)(4,4)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(0,-4)(3,4) 
\psVolume[linecolor=black!40,fillstyle=solid,
    fillcolor=yellow!40,opacity=0.4](0.5,2){12}{x sqrt 2 mul} 
\psplot[algebraic,linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed]{0}{2}{2*sqrt(x)}
\psplot[algebraic,linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed]{0}{2}{-2*sqrt(x)}
\psplot[algebraic,linecolor=red,linewidth=1pt]{0.5}{2}{2*sqrt(x)}
\pscustom[opacity=0.4,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,linestyle=none]{%
  \psplot[algebraic]{0.5}{2}{2*sqrt(x)}
  \psline(2,0)(0.5,0)}
\uput[0](2.1,2.8){\textcolor{red}{$y=2\cdot\sqrt{x}$}}
\psline(2,0)(3,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As I said, I'm total novice at this. So can you please do me the favour of explaining this pdflatex command?

Comment: @JustCurious: You don't know how to use `pdflatex` from within TeXStudio?

Comment: ```Package pst-pdf Warning: File `pdf-pics.pdf' not found.``` is the error I get after running it from shell. What should I do next? @MoneyOrientedProgrammer

Comment: @JustCurious: Remove the first two `\usepackage` in the code above and leave the last one which is `\usepackage{pst-func}`. Now compilet the file with `xelatex filename.tex`. It takes several seconds to finish. If you want to save time, invoke the following  `latex filename.tex`, `dvips filename.dvi` and `ps2pdf filename.ps` in the order I wrote.

Comment: @JustCurious: https://latex.userpage.fu-berlin.de/TeXstudio-Konfiguration.pdf shows the configuration of TeXStudio (see page 11 for inserting the --shell-escape option).

Comment: Do we have any more resources on this (--shell-escape in texstudio)?

Comment: @JustCurious: That's pretty simple: Open the preferences for TeXstudio, go the the tab "Commands" and insert on the right side after the command name " -- shell-escape". That's all ...